# Flutter : How to implement auto-suggestion in the searchbox?

Tags: flutter, search, flutter-dependencies

I have an array of cryptocurrencies as such :

`List<String> cryptoCurrencies= ['btcusd','btceur','ethbtc','ethgbp'];`

I have created a search bar and I want the items to be auto-suggested whenever the user types 3 letters.

How can I achieve this?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this , you will get it.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Autocomplete-class.html

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const AutocompleteExampleApp());

class AutocompleteExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const AutocompleteExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Autocomplete Basic'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: AutocompleteBasicExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AutocompleteBasicExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const AutocompleteBasicExample({super.key});

  static const List<String> _kOptions = <String>[
    'aardvark',
    'bobcat',
    'chameleon',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Autocomplete<String>(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
          return const Iterable<String>.empty();
        }
        return _kOptions.where((String option) {
          return option.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        });
      },
      onSelected: (String selection) {
        debugPrint('You just selected $selection');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32837080)

Comment: Its Autocomplete Widget that can help you in this.
Link is an official flutter link, 
Code is written by google engineers so it will you give correct explanation than anyone else.

Comment: Links are likely to change. So it's better to post the related code and quote some text here.

Comment: hey , I have updated the now please run the code in place of list put your list.